# HTTP/2 should I start or plan refactoring

Tags: http, optimization, http2

HTTP/1.x has a problem called "head-of-line blocking"

HTTP/1.1 tried to fix this with pipelining

> > Multiplexing addresses these problems by allowing multiple request and response messages to be in flight at the same time; it’s even possible to intermingle parts of one message with another on the wire

Does this reason minimize importance of domain sharding for resource and also bundling resource, spriting images etc? If this is true, should I at least plan for a refactoring? And how does this work?

Comment: You should probably take a slow read of relevant docs in the Internet about the subject: http://daniel.haxx.se/http2/ . Short answer: yes, it depends, you need to work less (by *not* doing bundling and domain sharding).

Comment: @dsign even wikipedia used HTTP 1.0, long after HTTP/1.1 existed, its more about overall process, and thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Multiplexing takes every request and makes them into one request, therefore optimisations surrounding reducing the number of requests are far less useful than in HTTP 1. I would suggest that you plan for refactoring your site/app only if you are migrating your server to HTTP2. Modern browsers are adopting it, however server implementations vary. This was done to ensure that we as developers have the choice to upgrade to HTTP2, in contrast to a 'forced upgrade'.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11274052)

Comment: @KevinReid sure, i'll expand. Multiplexing takes every request and makes them into one request, therefore optimisations surrounding reducing the number of requests are far less useful than in HTTP 1. I would suggest that you plan for refactoring your site/app only if you are migrating your server to HTTP2. Modern browsers are adopting it, however server implementations vary. This was done to ensure that we as developers have the choice to upgrade to HTTP2, in contrast to a 'forced upgrade'.

Comment: Please [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35413112/edit) to include that information. Comments should be considered disposable.